# How to truncate a table after inserting data into another table using pl/sql?

Tags: sql, oracle, plsql

So i have a stored procedure that is transferring data from one table to another. However, i realized that if i don't truncate the first table (xml_hours_load), i may insert the same data over and over again when i eventually schedule this stored procedure into a regular job. How do i truncate the first table after loading the second? (xml_hours_Load_2). I've tried placing the truncate right after the insert of the 2nd table but pl/sql throws me an error ...

```
CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE insertXMLDataTransfer(
 vROW_ID in xml_hours_load_2.ROW_ID%TYPE,
 vUTC_Offset in xml_hours_load_2.UTC_OFFSET%TYPE,
 vPROCESSED in xml_hours_load_2.PROCESSED%TYPE,
 vDATA_DATE in xml_hours_load_2.Data_Date%TYPE,
 vHR_UTC in xml_hours_load_2.HR_UTC%TYPE,
 vVALUE_TX in xml_hours_load_2.VALUE_TX%TYPE,
 vHR in xml_hours_load_2.HR%TYPE,
 vHR_NUM in xml_hours_load_2.HR_NUM%TYPE,
 vDATA_CODE in xml_hours_load_2.DATA_CODE%TYPE,
 vDATA_TYPE in xml_hours_load_2.DATA_TYPE%TYPE
                                              )
AS
BEGIN
  INSERT INTO xml_hours_load_2(ROW_ID, UTC_OFFSET, PROCESSED, DATA_DATE,     HR_UTC, VALUE_TX, HR, HR_NUM, DATA_CODE, DATA_TYPE)
       VALUES (vROW_ID, vUTC_Offset, vPROCESSED, vDATA_DATE, vHR_UTC, vVALUE_TX, vHR, vHR_NUM, vDATA_CODE, vDATA_TYPE);
  TRUNCATE table xml_hours_load;
COMMIT;
END;
/

DECLARE 
 vROW_ID xml_hours_load_2.ROW_ID%TYPE;
 vUTC_Offset xml_hours_load_2.UTC_OFFSET%TYPE;
 vPROCESSED xml_hours_load_2.PROCESSED%TYPE;
 vDATA_DATE xml_hours_load_2.Data_Date%TYPE;
 vHR_UTC xml_hours_load_2.HR_UTC%TYPE;
 vVALUE_TX xml_hours_load_2.VALUE_TX%TYPE;
 vHR xml_hours_load_2.HR%TYPE;
 vHR_NUM xml_hours_load_2.HR_NUM%TYPE;
 vDATA_CODE xml_hours_load_2.DATA_CODE%TYPE;
 vDATA_TYPE xml_hours_load_2.DATA_TYPE%TYPE;
  CURSOR cXMLHoursCursor IS (SELECT ROW_ID, UTC_OFFSET, PROCESSED, DATA_DATE, HR_UTC, VALUE_TX, HR, HR_NUM, DATA_CODE, DATA_TYPE FROM xml_hours_load);
BEGIN
  For v in cXMLHoursCursor LOOP
  insertXMLDataTransfer(v.ROW_ID, v.UTC_OFFSET, v.PROCESSED, v.DATA_DATE, v.HR_UTC, v.VALUE_TX, v.HR, v.HR_NUM, v.DATA_CODE, v.DATA_TYPE);
  COMMIT;
END LOOP;
END;
/
```

Comment: Have you considered adding a primary or unique key to prevent duplicates? TRUNCATEs are pretty much unrecoverable - without actually going back to a backup. Seeing TRUNCATE code in your procedure makes me very nervous for your data.

Comment: would the stored procedure error out if some primary keys (that already exist) in the second table try to be inserted a second time? I already had a primary key set for the xml_hours_load and xml_hours_load_2 tables

Comment: the records would go in that could the others would get a ORA-00001: unique constraint violated...

Comment: see this example https://asktom.oracle.com/pls/apex/f?p=100:11:0::::P11_QUESTION_ID:9524231800346013638

Comment: would that stop all of the records from being inserted?> or just the ones that are duplicates? seems like when i test out the procedure with duplicate entries, the procedure errors out all together and doesnt insert anything

Comment: I need to look at your code again, but you can have your cake and eat it too.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't truncate it in PL/SQL directly; you'll have to do it using dynamic SQL, i.e.

```
your_first_query;

execute immediate ('truncate table xml_hours_load');

your_second_query;
```

**[EDIT]**

Saying that you got an error (IMMEDIATE must be declared), well - you did something wrong; have a look at this example:

```
SQL> create table test (id number);

Table created.

SQL> begin
  2    execute immediate ('truncate table test');
  3  end;
  4  /

PL/SQL procedure successfully completed.

SQL>
```

IF you could edit your post and show us what you did, it might be easier to assist further.

Comment: thanks! i just had to embed it within the first code block!

Comment: Aha; OK, so you found the reason. *We have met the enemy, and they is us* :)